# ¿Cómo hago para crear un enlace al pie de página?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

¿Cómo hago para crear un enlace (Política de Privacidad) que sólo aparezca al pie de la página principal, y no en cada una de las entradas? Estoy creando mi web con WordPress y la plantilla que estoy usando (Receptar) no tiene pie de página, por lo tanto no puedo añadir Widgets ni nada, tan solo texto...

Gracias de antemano :)

[image: Una imagen para que veaís a que me refiero]

Comment: Si estas creando el sitio usando HTML, CSS y JS puro, simplemente agrega la etiqueta del enlace en la pagina inicial y no en las demas

Comment: No, estoy creando mi web con WordPress pero el tema que estoy utilizando no tiene pie de página...

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras eso en tu pregunta tambien :)

Comment: Ya lo he editado, disculpa. Estoy utilizando el plugin Insert Headers and Footers para insterar los códigos y no meter la pata por error.

Comment: ¿Has visto la documentación de wordpress?

Comment: Sí, la he visto. Pero no viene nada al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto si quieres que te salga en todas paginas:
Política de Privacidad

Si quieres que solamente salga en una en concreto, prueba en buscar un plugin que te permita en hacer lo que tu quieras. Ten en cuenta que estos créditos de la pie de pagina sirve normalmente para poner el copyright, tal y como pone en la descripción, por eso siempre aparecerá en todas las entradas.

Un saludo.